Getting information No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8
Here is the link to the .gff file. https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3x463ykcfl87ncdi3onjn/TcDB-66.gff?rlkey=chym6az6u144n6r9ltstqx54f&dl=0
I am facing difficulties whenever I run the code below in rStudio and under R.4.4.1
# script used to get gene info
library(rtracklayer)
library(tidyverse)
 
Tc_genes<-import.gff3("~/Documents/congoScell/Annotation/TcDB-66.gff") %>%
as_tibble() %>%
#filter(type =="protein_coding_gene") %>%
select(ID, description) %>%
mutate(GeneSeurat = gsub("_", "-", ID)) %>%
mutate(GeneDescription = paste0(ID, "::", description))
Tc_genes$GeneDescription<-gsub('\\+', ' ', Tc_genes$GeneDescription)
Tc_genes<-Tc_genes[ends_with(".1",vars=Tc_genes$ID),]
Tc_genes[]<- lapply(Tc_genes, gsub, pattern = ".1", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE)

I have attached a photo of the .gff file.
Whenever I pull this script as a source in, I get the information:
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
I am wondering how this can be solved. Anyone able to help please sort me out.
I have tried to check if someone has had issues as mine, and found some but not related.

Is this causing a problem? Seems like a warning rather than an error. And it's most likely the case that your file is UTF-8 unless you have a reason to believe it's not.

As I wrote in Staging Ground,  rtracklayer is abandonware, not having been touched since 2011.  If you go to CRAN and get Rgff,  you will have success.  I tested it with your example file and everything worked.

Thank you for this response. would you please help with the correct code. I already have Rgff. Thanks.

@erickotieno  I haven't used Rgff other than to examine your file.  I recommend reading the man pages for the functions included in that library.
